# Pyside2 QListView drag and drop reordering based on data from a user role does not work as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

I am running this on Windows 10 and Python 3.7+ (tested in 3.7 and 3.9 with the same result).

I have a custom QListView and a QStandardItemModel with a QSortFilterProxyModel in between. I am using custom user-role data (UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE) to reorder items in the list view and upon drag-drop re-ordering, I update this custom data so that the reordered item's "twin", which is currently *inactive*, from the combo_box has the same data as the active item for the QSortFilterProxyModel to sort the way I need it to.

Below is a reproducible example. In the example, if I drag *Item_1* to the bottom of the *list_view* and use the *combo_box* to switch to its twin, *Item_2*, *Item_2* moves to the top of the *list_view* when I expect it to be at the bottom where *Item_1* was. But if I switch back to *Item_1* using the *combo_box* while selecting *Item_2*, *Item_1* is still at the bottom of the *list_view*. What am I doing wrong?

I have defined the *sortRole* in the *filter_model* as the *UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE* and have overridden the *lessThan* method for it to custom sort, as well as update the *ORDER_ROLE* for the *Item_2* to match the *ORDER_ROLE* of *Item_1* in *list_view*'s *dropEvent* using *Item_1*'s row number. Filtering seems to work as expected(?) where once *Item_1* is swapped with *Item_2* using the *combo_box*, *Item_1*'s *ACTIVE_ROLE* is set to False and *Item_2*'s *ACTIVE_ROLE* is set to True. However, this seems to happen despite *QSortFilterProxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter* is by default set to False. Am I misunderstanding how *QSortFilterProxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter* works?

I have also noticed dropping the item on another item makes the dropped item disappear. Any thoughts on why this may be happening?

```
from enum import IntEnum
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class UserRoles(IntEnum):
    ACTIVE_ROLE = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1
    ORDER_ROLE = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 2
    TWIN_ROLE = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 3


class MvcModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        
        items_list = ["Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3", "Item_4", "Item_5", "Item_6"]

        for i in range(len(items_list)):
            data = items_list[i]
            
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(data)
            
            if i % 2 == 0:
                item.setData(True, UserRoles.ACTIVE_ROLE)
                item.setData(items_list[i+1], UserRoles.TWIN_ROLE)
            else:
                item.setData(False, UserRoles.ACTIVE_ROLE)
                item.setData(items_list[i-1], UserRoles.TWIN_ROLE)

            item.setData(i + 1, UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)

            self.appendRow(item)


class MvcProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setSortRole(UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE)
        self.setDynamicSortFilter(True)


    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        index = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        return index.data(UserRoles.ACTIVE_ROLE) is True

    def lessThan(self, source_left, source_right):
        return int(source_left.data(UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE)) < int(
            source_right.data(UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE)
        )


class MvcList(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.set_view_params()

        self.data_model = MvcModel(self)
        self.filter_model = MvcProxyModel(self)

        self.filter_model.setSourceModel(self.data_model)
        self.setModel(self.filter_model)

        self.clicked.connect(self.item_selected)

    def set_view_params(self):
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def item_selected(self, index):
        self.parent().update_combo_box.emit(index)


    def dropEvent(self, event):
        super().dropEvent(event)

        index = event.source().currentIndex()
                
        alt_item = index.data(UserRoles.TWIN_ROLE)
        alt_item = self.data_model.findItems(alt_item)
        alt_index = alt_item[0].index()

        alt_index = self.model().mapFromSource(alt_index)

        self.filter_model.setData(index, str(index.row()+1), UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE)
        self.filter_model.setData(alt_index, str(index.row()+1), UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE)


class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    update_combo_box = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.update_combo_box.connect(self.update_combo)

        self.setup_ui()
        self.combo_box.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.switch_to_twin)
        self.show()


    def setup_ui(self):
        self.list_view = MvcList(self)
        self.combo_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)

        self.hbox_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.list_view)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.combo_box)
        
        self.setLayout(self.hbox_layout)
        
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 200)

    def update_combo(self, index):
        self.combo_box.blockSignals(True)
        
        self.combo_box.clear()
        self.combo_box.addItem(index.data())
        self.combo_box.addItem(index.data(UserRoles.TWIN_ROLE))

        self.combo_box.blockSignals(False)


    def get_row_num(self, index):
        increment = 0

        for i in range(self.list_view.model().rowCount()):
            item = self.list_view.data_model.item(i, 0)

            if item.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole) != index.data():
                continue

            if item.data(UserRoles.ACTIVE_ROLE):
               increment += 1 

            return increment+1

        return -1

    def switch_to_twin(self, index):
        current_text = self.combo_box.currentText()

        index_to = self.list_view.data_model.findItems(current_text)
        if not index_to:
            return

        index_to = index_to[0].index()

        index_from = self.list_view.data_model.findItems(index_to.data(UserRoles.TWIN_ROLE))
        if not index_from:
            return

        index_from = index_from[0].index()

        index_from_row = self.get_row_num(index_from)

        print(self.list_view.data_model.setData(index_to, True, UserRoles.ACTIVE_ROLE))
        print(self.list_view.data_model.setData(index_from , False, UserRoles.ACTIVE_ROLE))
        print(index_from.data(), index_to.data(), str(index_from_row+1))
        print(self.list_view.data_model.setData(index_to, str(index_from.row()+1), UserRoles.ORDER_ROLE))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        
        test_widget = TestWidget()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: There are various issues with your code: 1. you can't use the `currentIndex()` in the drop operation with the `data_model` (try to `print()` the first `setData()` and it will return `False`): the index argument of `setData()` must belong to the same model, use `self.filter_model` instead; 2. you're not doing any filtering, as `sort()` is never called; 3. every time the combo is cleared (and a first item is added), `switch_to_twin` is called; 4. you shouldn't try to directly access another child by querying the parent (like you did in `self.parent().combo_box`), use a signal instead;

Comment: 5. if you want to prevent drop on items, you must unset the drag flag: `item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)` (see the explanation about [`dragDropOverwriteMode`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dragDropOverwriteMode-prop)). I'm not completely sure about what the actual use of this will be, if you could clarify the final purpose we might be of more help (I'm under the impression that you might be doing something too complex than it could be); also consider that for advanced usage and management, a QAbstractItemModel/QAbstractListModel subclass might be better.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all the issues! I have fixed them and updated the code above. What I am basically trying to achieve is that with a list_view and a combo_box as above, each item in the model is linked to another item that's inactive. When a user wants to switch from an active item in the list_view, set using the active role, to the inactive item using the combo_box, the inactive item must show in the same position as the original active item. In above example, drag-dropping Item_1 elsewhere in the list_view and switching to Item_2, Item_2 should be in the same position as Item_1 was in.

Comment: I believe I understood the "logic" of those items, what's unclear is the *final purpose*. Do you actually need those items in pairs? Are you ever gonna show/access all of them? From what you're describing, it seems more like an implementation problem, and you probably don't need any pair, but just a better logic behind item data access and sorting. I strongly suggest you to reconsider the whole thing, as mixing model sorting *and* user sorting can become very (and probably unnecessarily) complex, especially if sorting is done for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Besides, you shouldn't emit a signal for the parent, as you're doing almost the same conceptual error as before: accessing an object of the parent indiscriminately. While you may "know" that the parent is always a `TestWidget` class, that's not the point: not only the parent could be another class type (that doesn't have that signal) - so you're just making an assumption, but it's conceptually wrong from the OOP perspective. Using signals is the correct approach, but the signal should belong to `MvcList`, and you should then do `self.list_view.update_combo_box.connect(self.update_combo)`.

Comment: I have only submitted a minimum reproducible example here. Without going deep into its functionality due to IP, for each active item, there can be multiple inactive (but essential) items and at some point, the user of the tool will want to switch to another of its linked items with their custom user data displayed using a QStyledItemDelegate for each item.

Gotcha about the signal. Will update my main code accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: For the model sorting and user sorting to remain somewhat consistent, I am using the ORDER_ROLE, which always has (or must have) the correct number for the order in which each item (and its linked items) should be displayed in the list_view, and used the QSortFilterProxyModel to do the custom sorting and filtering. This ORDER_ROLE along with other ROLES that I haven't given here are displayed on a custom widget using the delegate.